# Why am I getting a seg fault in this C program ? Dealing with fscanf and printf

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, scanf

I have tried a tons of things pertaining to the `fscanf` and the print functions, the `Fight` function is in a different file and has this prototype

```
void Fight( char * combatant1, int ac1, int hp1, int hitbonus1, int damagebonus1, char * combatant2, int ac2, int hp2, int hitbonus2, int damagebonus2);
```

But I don't think that is where the error is coming from. I still get a seg fault when the line is commented out. Can anyone help me with this? The data Files look like this

> Name ## ## ## ##

Here is my code

```
void printInfo(FILE *f1, FILE *f2){
    char* name1;
    char* name2;
    int armor1;
    int armor2;
    int hp1;
    int hp2;
    int hb1;
    int hb2;
    int db1;
    int db2;
    fscanf(f1, "%s %d %d %d %d", name1, &armor1,&hp1,&hb1,&db1);
    printf("\nName=%s, Armor=%d, Hit Points=%d, Hit Bonus=%d, Damage Bonus=%d", name1,armor1,hp1,hb1,db1);
    fscanf(f2, "%s %d %d %d %d", name2, &armor2,&hp2,&hb2,&db2);
    printf("\nName=%s, Armor=%d, Hit Points=%d, Hit Bonus=%d, Damage Bonus=%d", name2,armor2,hp2,hb2,db2);
    //Fight(name1,armor1,hp1,hb1,db1,name2,armor2,hp2,hb2,db2);
}
```

Comment: Where do `name1` and `name2` point to?

Comment: name1 and name2 in the fscanf are suppose to go to the char pointers decalred above

Comment: You did not allocate memory for the contents of name1 and name2..

Comment: You forgot to allocate: `char* name1 = malloc(size)` and `char* name2 = malloc(size)`

Answer (score 6):

Every pointer, after its declaration, needs to be initialized to a valid address. And that address, in order to be valid, needs to be allocated. Your pointers

```
char* name1;
char* name2;
```

don't actually point to valid memory locations. So, when `fscanf` tries to write names to the addresses pointed by `name1` and `name2`, it actually writes to invalid addresses causing segmentation fault.

You can choose between two options. Allocating names statically, either as global variables or locally in the stack area, using arrays

```
char name1[50];
char name2[50];
```

or dynamically

```
char* name1 =  malloc(50);// That is (50*sizeof char). But sizeof(char) is 1.
char* name2 =  malloc(50);
```

In this example 50 bytes were allocated as the maximum size of the string. In order to store in them at most 49 characters (one char is required for the string terminator), you can use proper string format in `fscanf`. For example

```
fscanf(f1, "%49s %d %d %d %d", name1, &armor1,&hp1,&hb1,&db1);
```

---

### Using *data structures* to optimize code

Though it is unrelated to your issue, I notice how your `Fight` function has 10 parameters:

```
void Fight( char * combatant1, int ac1, int hp1, int hitbonus1, int damagebonus1, char * combatant2, int ac2, int hp2, int hitbonus2, int damagebonus2);
```

Defining a function with too many parameters sometimes may cause inefficiency in terms of stack consumption (especially in embedded systems, where only the first 3 or 4 parameters use the processor registers, with all the others parameters copied to the stack).

The solution is using data structures. In your case you have exactly 2 combatants, each of them with 5 properties. So, defining a combatant structure as follows

```
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int ac;
    int hp;
    int hitbonus;
    int damagebonus;
} Combatant_t;
```

would simplyfy `Fight()` function's interface, as you could just pass to it two pointers to combatants. Its signature would become:

```
void Fight(Combatant_t *cb1, Combatant_t *cb2);
```

Your `printInfo()` would become:

```
void printInfo(FILE *f1, FILE *f2)
{
    Combatant_t *comb1 = malloc( sizeof(Combatant_t) );
    Combatant_t *comb2 = malloc( sizeof(Combatant_t) );
    /* Note: malloc might fail. Remember to manage that scenario */ 
    
    /* memset to 0 newly allocated structs */
    memset( comb1, 0, sizeof(*comb1) );
    memset( comb2, 0, sizeof(*comb2) );
    
    fscanf(f1, "%49s %d %d %d %d", comb1->name, &(comb1->ac), &(comb1->hp), &(comb1->hitbonus), &(comb1->damagebonus));
    printf("\nName=%s, Armor=%d, Hit Points=%d, Hit Bonus=%d, Damage Bonus=%d", comb1->name, comb1->ac, comb1->hp, comb1->hitbonus, comb1->damagebonus);
    fscanf(f1, "%49s %d %d %d %d", comb2->name, &(comb2->ac), &(comb2->hp), &(comb2->hitbonus), &(comb2->damagebonus));
    printf("\nName=%s, Armor=%d, Hit Points=%d, Hit Bonus=%d, Damage Bonus=%d", comb2->name, comb2->ac, comb2->hp, comb2->hitbonus, comb2->damagebonus);

    //Fight( comb1, comb2);

     /* Remember to free comb1 an comb2 as soon as you don't need them anymore */
}
```

Comment: by *definition* `sizeof char` is 1 = > useless to do `*sizeof char`

Comment: @bruno I know but.. my goal was explaining the general rule to someone not familiar to memory allocation. See my edit in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Trying to match the pointer type in the `sizeof` calculation  is easier to write, maintain and review with `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr * N);` which does away with  _type_ issues.  Likewise for `memset( comb1, 0, sizeof *comb1 );`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'll modify that (but I'll leave parenthesis).